# Unknown build error, 'Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, exception, compiler-construction, build-process

We have VS.Net solution with 20 projects in it.

Occasionaly, in VS.NET, when we try to build/debug our solution, we get following error:

**Unknown build error, 'Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown**

Only way to "fix" this issue is to reopen Visual Studio and then solution build goes well, but again after some time OutOfMemory exception occur again. It's really annoying to reopen Visual Studio couple times a day, so do you know some workaround for this issue ?

Comment: +1 I have the same issue and have never been able to track it down. It's not only on build, either; I've had this on opening a form designer after VS has been open a while. Closing and reopening VS fixes the issue 100% of the time and at least Task Manager thinks there's plenty of memory left.

Comment: Are you using ReSharper or other add-ins? Try disabling them with Tools->Add-in Manager, just to see if they're part of the problem. Also, does this happen if you're just repeatedly doing builds, with no debug or unit test runs?

Comment: I'm using ReSharper, waiting for next OutOfMemoryException and I'll try to turn it off to see what will happen.

Thanks

Comment: Turning off resharper didn't help. And like you said, I'm repeatingly doing builds, two or three builds, and then debug. Probably it's some VS.NET issue :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JetBrains is aware of this issue, and they provide some fix for it, using this fix solved my problems for now:

http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/ReSharper/OutOfMemoryException+Fix

---

Edit:
However, OutOfMemory exception is occuring again, but it's not as often as it is when I dont use this JetBrains fix.

Answer (score 2):

According to what Microsoft recommends, it is not a good idea to have lots of projects within a single solution.

Check out this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949755 .

But the solution suggested in the article is not something that be straight away used, because of the code refactoring costs involved.

Have you tried building the solution from outside the IDE. (Something like MSBUILD). That might help.

Comment: We didn't separate our code in few solutions for the reason you stated: refactoring

Building outside of IDE works well, only problem is VS.NET build

Answer (score 2):

I have the same Issue if I use ReSharper and run several UnitTests (with enabled CodeCoverage).

I also assume this is a ReSharper problem. And since I disble it while I'm running Unittest the Exception never appears again.

BTW - Disabling it when the exception throws (as mentioned in the comments above) doesn't help, because of disabling it while VS is running will not unload it from memory. The only way to force the unload is to tear down all AppDomains which have loaded the DLL. In a VS Package scenario this means you have to tear down the entire VS process :(

Comment: Guess you're right. I turned off ReSharper, restarted VS and I'm waiting couple of hours to see if it will happen again. If not you get +1 :) and I'll see what to do then with ReSharper :/

Answer (score 2):

Or you can just minimize Visual Studio for about 10 seconds (see in task manager how the memory usage of devenv.exe drops when minimized). This works for me in most cases.I rarely have to close VS to get rid of this error.

Answer (score -1):

VS reinstallation is temporary solution. Jus increase your machine Virtual memory size. this resolves this issue.

ref below link - 
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/change-virtual-memory-size#1TC=windows-7